# Should I use a backslash before global functions in PHP even if is not needed?

Tags: php

There is a recommendation on https://phptherightway.com/pages/The-Basics.html using backslash for global functions. Take a look at this code:

```
<?php

 namespace myspace;
 
 class MyClass
 {
      public $myvar = 'test';
      public function myfunction()
      {
           $withoutBackslash = json_encode($this->myvar);
           $withBackslash    = \json_encode($this->myvar);
          return [$withBackslash, $withoutBackslash];
      }
  }
```

How is better with or without backslash? I never used them before should I change my code in either direction (removing or adding)?

Comment: it should have backslash, i think it's better. With it the interpreter should use it in global namespace.

Comment: This should be done if global function with the same name exists and there is no benefits to it doing it unless necessary

Comment: @PascalTovohery so if it is "easier" for the interpreter with the backslash, that would translate into a micro optimisation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine that you define the same function name yourself. You will still need to have a way to call the global one. Putting the backslash before the name of the function will forward you to the global namespace, therefore you will call the global one.

There may be tiny performace gain that way, but it's much harder to read. Personally I would not put that backslash unless it is necessarily.

Comment: Are you sure there is any performance gains? I also feel its harder to read and not as clear.

Comment: Check here: https://veewee.github.io/blog/optimizing-php-performance-by-fq-function-calls/

Comment: Thanks for the input! I am working at a project that uses a lot of backslashes like in my example and wanted to know if I should remove them... so probably not.

Answer (score 7):

No, since you do not have global functions, only classes, then there is no point in separate them. They are using `\fopen` because they have `phptherightway\fopen`

In that case writing just `fopen` will refer to `phptherightway\fopen` instead of global `fopen`

Comment: Yes, I know, I was wondering if there's any benefit on using it even if we don't have a function with the same name as the global one. Like small performance tweak or making sure no mistakes are made on the future.

Comment: @MihaiCrăiță So as you single benefit is that you can access both namespaced and non-namespaced functions with same name. In my opinion it's more clear to read code without `\`. Main rule: keep it consistently across code

Comment: I also think is more clear without. I am working on a project that have this things messed up and made me think it might have some other benefits I missed.

Answer (score 4):

I think you've missunderstood the idea. Take a look at their example:

```
<?php
namespace phptherightway;

// Our function name is the same as an internal function.
function fopen()
{
    // Execute the function from the global space by adding '\'
    $file = \fopen();    
}
```

They've defined an `fopen()` function that should be called from its namespace: `\phptherightway\fopen()`.

Inside that function, they call the native PHP `fopen()` function and it needs the backslash to do so (from global namespace) and avoid calling itself.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I was wondering if there's any benefit if we don't have a function with the same name.

Comment: It is just an example, you don't need to re-write internal functions, but maybe one of your projects has a function already declared on another script that you're wanting to use. Then you need namespaces.