# Using global function with imported namespace

Tags: php, import, syntax, namespaces, global

So recently my colleague suggested prefixing global PHP functions with `\` or importing them via `use function`. He suggested some performance improvements as prefixing the function will tell PHP to import the function directly from global namespace.

I could not find any official guidelines in regards to that. So my question is which option is preferred

1.

```
<?php

$myVar = ltrim(' randomstring');
```

2. 

```
<?php

$myVar = \ltrim(' randomstring');
```

3. 

```
<?php
use function ltrim;

$myVar = ltrim(' randomstring');
```

Comment: Not sure if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62568683/should-i-use-a-backslah-before-global-functions-in-php-even-if-is-not-needed helps.

Comment: My first suggestion would be to measure the performance impact in your code. For tight loops with thousands of calls it might matter slightly, but once you throw any IO into the mix (DB, FS, etc.) you probably won't really notice anything. For most people I think this will come down to style and personal preference. I did this briefly, maybe 6 months or so, but then yanked almost all of it out because it was harder to read in hindsight. I'd encourage you to read [this](https://externals.io/message/107953) and [this](https://externals.io/message/107967) from the PHP core discussions.